# Why is this seemingly Legit MySQL Query giving errors?

Tags: mysql, sql

First, I have one Table named **goals**

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | member_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  8 |         4 | 2016-08-08 15:36:06 | 2016-08-08 15:36:06 |
|  9 |         4 | 2016-08-08 15:38:37 | 2016-08-08 15:38:37 |
| 10 |         4 | 2016-08-08 15:44:13 | 2016-08-08 15:44:13 |
| 11 |         4 | 2016-08-08 16:45:14 | 2016-08-08 16:45:14 |
| 12 |         4 | 2016-08-08 16:54:10 | 2016-08-08 16:54:10 |
| 13 |         4 | 2016-08-08 17:04:13 | 2016-08-08 17:04:13 |
| 14 |         4 | 2016-08-08 17:08:09 | 2016-08-08 17:08:09 |
| 15 |         4 | 2016-08-08 17:11:17 | 2016-08-08 17:11:17 |
| 16 |         4 | 2016-08-08 17:16:53 | 2016-08-08 17:16:53 |
| 17 |         4 | 2016-08-08 17:19:39 | 2016-08-08 17:19:39 |
| 18 |         4 | 2016-08-08 17:30:53 | 2016-08-08 17:30:53 |
| 19 |         4 | 2016-08-08 17:37:27 | 2016-08-08 17:37:27 |
| 20 |         4 | 2016-08-09 09:32:09 | 2016-08-09 09:32:09 |
| 21 |         4 | 2016-08-09 12:08:29 | 2016-08-09 12:08:29 |
| 22 |         4 | 2016-08-09 12:16:51 | 2016-08-09 12:16:51 |
| 23 |         4 | 2016-08-09 12:27:48 | 2016-08-09 12:27:48 |
| 24 |         4 | 2016-08-09 12:41:59 | 2016-08-09 12:41:59 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
# ... other rows omitted for brevity
```

Then there's another table named **goal_cycles**

```
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| id | goal_id | start_date          | end_date            | cycle_status |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| 14 |       8 | 2016-08-09 15:35:59 | 2016-08-18 15:35:59 | active       |
| 15 |       9 | 2016-08-09 15:38:33 | 2016-08-13 15:38:33 | active       |
| 16 |      10 | 2016-08-09 15:44:11 | 2016-08-11 15:44:11 | active       |
| 17 |      11 | 2016-08-09 16:45:11 | 2016-08-14 16:45:11 | active       |
| 18 |      12 | 2016-08-09 16:54:08 | 2016-08-13 16:54:08 | active       |
| 19 |      13 | 2016-08-09 17:04:11 | 2016-08-13 17:04:11 | active       |
| 20 |      14 | 2016-08-09 17:08:06 | 2016-08-12 17:08:06 | active       |
| 21 |      15 | 2016-08-09 17:11:13 | 2016-08-10 17:11:13 | active       |
| 22 |      16 | 2016-08-09 17:16:50 | 2016-08-10 17:16:50 | active       |
| 23 |      17 | 2016-08-09 17:19:36 | 2016-08-16 17:19:36 | active       |
| 24 |      18 | 2016-08-09 17:30:50 | 2016-08-12 17:30:50 | active       |
| 25 |      19 | 2016-08-09 17:37:23 | 2016-08-12 17:37:23 | active       |
| 26 |      20 | 2016-08-10 09:32:06 | 2016-08-14 09:32:06 | passive      |
| 27 |      21 | 2016-08-10 12:08:26 | 2016-08-19 12:08:26 | passive      |
| 28 |      22 | 2016-08-10 12:16:48 | 2016-08-14 12:16:48 | passive      |
| 29 |      23 | 2016-08-10 12:27:44 | 2016-08-14 12:27:44 | passive      |
| 30 |      24 | 2016-08-10 12:41:54 | 2016-08-19 12:41:54 | passive      |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
# ... other rows omitted for brevity
```

**THE TASK**: I need to update ***goal_cycles*** for all ***goals*** where **`memberId = 4`** and where **`cycle_status = active`** in the following manner;

1. Update the `cycle_status = passive`
2. Set `start_date = start_date + 3days`
3. Set `end_date = end_date + 3days`

So I wrote the following MySQL Query;

```
update goal_cycles gc 
    set gc.cycle_status = 'passive', 
    set gc.start_date = DATE_ADD(gc.start_date, INTERVAL 3 DAY), 
    set gc.end_date = DATE_ADD(gc.end_date, INTERVAL 3 DAY) 
where gc.goal_id in (select g.id from goals g where g.member_id = 4)
and gc.cycle_status = 'active'
```

This seems to me like a legit ***mysql query*** but I get the following error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set gc.start_date = DATE_ADD(gc.start_date, INTERVAL 3 DAY),
set gc.end_date = ' at line 3
```

Please I need the MySQL experts to point out what's exactly the problem with this query and how to rightly fix it based on the task requirement.

Comment: Remember that the MySQL documentation is usually extremely specific about the structure of statements. [The `UPDATE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) should be pretty easy to discern if you know where to look. There's no shame in having the documentation open in one tab at all times when writing queries. It's how you get things right the first time.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the heads up. I'd make a point to - on my way home - NEVER blindly rush through documentations next time. Appreciate the advice. Cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you repeated `set`. It should appear only ONCE in the query:

```
update table foo
    set field1 = value1,
        field2 = value2,
        field3 = value3,
        etc...
```

So, no, it's not valid syntax.

Comment: Oh... my! What a terrible oversight... my brain must have been hibernating at the time... I even checked the MySQL docs and was too blind to notice my horrible syntax flaw. Thanks @Marc-B